# How to obtain each group match in a regex repetition

Tags: java, regex

Is there a way to obtain all matches to a given group that is inside a repetition (using Java's built-in regex API)? If so, how?

Here's an example ([live code](http://ideone.com/54vS9O)):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("IF N = '([^']*)'( OR N = '([^']*)')* THEN");
String script = "IF N = 'abc' OR N = 'def' OR N = 'ghi' THEN";
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(script);

for( int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++){
    System.out.println(i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
}
```

How would I obtain all of the individual matches to group 3 (the part to the right of the second = sign)? Right now, the loop above only returns the second match ("ghi").

If this is not possible, suggestions for other methods are welcomed, but I'm looking for the simplest thing that works. My general use case is matching against code snippets like above that fall into a set of categories. I already have regex's to match each category, but not an easy way to extract out all the important information that is matched by the groups.

Comment: You are probably better off using a real parser rather than regexes there... [I happen to maintain one](https://github.com/fge/grappa), if you are interested (sorry for the self ad)

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping to avoid the complexity of having to write a real parser.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this by using a capturing group around the repetition and re-parsing the full match to the repetition using a second, smaller regex.

```
String script = "IF N = 'abc' OR N = 'def' OR N = 'ghi' THEN";

// Groups:
// 1 = comparison value
// 2 = "or" list
//    1 = "or" comparison value
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("IF N = '([^']*)'(( OR N = '([^']*)')*) THEN");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(script);
System.out.println("matches: "+ matcher.matches());
System.out.println("if "+matcher.group(1));

// just the "OR ..." parts
String orList = matcher.group(2);
Pattern innerPattern = Pattern.compile(" OR N = '([^']*)'");
Matcher innerMatcher = innerPattern.matcher(orList);
while(innerMatcher.find()){
    System.out.println("  or "+innerMatcher.group(1));
}
```

Yields:

```
matches: true
if abc
  or def
  or ghi
```